# read from context items in httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, pipeline, httpmodule

I have a http module in my asp.net c# web application.

I insert a value into context items on the OnPreInit of my Page.

I want to read this value from the context items in my httpmodule. However I can't find which event in my httpmodule this can be read at. The latest I have tried is the PreRequestHandlerExecute event.

Could someone point me in the correct direction what event in the httpmodule I can read this value from the context items?

Answer (score 1):

You have to intercept request event after the handler and the state have been assigned.
Use PostAcquireRequestState event in your particular scenario

```
context.PostAcquireRequestState += OnPostAcquireRequestState;
```